# Getting a specific div tag with Beautful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Usually I would just call the div by a class name but it's not unique. The **only** unique thing the div tag has is the word "*data-sc-replace*" right after div. This is a shorten example of the source code

```
<div data-sc-replace data-sc-slot="1234" class = "inlineblock" data-sc-params="{'magnet': 'magnet:?......'extension': 'epub', 'stream': '' }"></div>
```

How would I go about calling the word "data-sc-replace" if it's not attached to a class or an id?

This is the code I have

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url_to_scrape = "http://example.com"
 r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
 list = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'inlineblock'})

 print(list)

 # list = soup.findAll("div", "data-sc-params")
 # list = soup.find('data-sc-replace')
 # list = soup.find('data-sc-params')
 # list = soup.find('div', {'class':'inlineblock'}, 'data-sc-params')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS query selectors. Finds all `divs` with `data-sc-replace` attributes.

```
result = soup.select('div[data-sc-replace]')
```

Answer (score 0):

That distinctive mark seems to be an HTML attribute without value. So try this:

```
soup.find('div', attrs = {'data-sc-replace': ''})
# or use find_all() to get all such div containers
```

Comment: When I replace it the output is 
<class 'list'>

Comment: `find_all()` should give you a `ResultSet` object (which is a list and can be accessed with list notation) and `find()` a `Tag` object, as far as I know. Try to access the first element of that list with `list[0]`.